# groupby operations with conditionals in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to perform a groupby operation in pandas. For example, I want to group  `patient` column and if the `treatment` column `== X` transfer correponding `doctor` value to the new column called `nurse` .

For example: df

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'patient': ['a','a','a','b','b','b'],
   ....:           'treatment': ['X','Y','Y','X','Z','Z'],
                   'doctor': ['1','2','2','2','3','3']})

  patient treatment doctor
0       a         X      1
1       a         Y      2
2       a         Y      2
3       b         X      2
4       b         Z      3
5       b         Z      3
```

I tried

```
df=df.assign(nurse=np.where(df.['treatment'].str.contains('X'),df.groupby('patient')['doctor'], np.nan))
```

but getting error

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

the expected output

```
    patient treatment doctor  nurse
0       a         X      1      1
1       a         Y      2      1
2       a         Y      2      1
3       b         X      2      2
4       b         Z      3      2
5       b         Z      3      2
```

How can I achieve this output ?

thx

Comment: And for the rest of values (when treatment is not X) are you supposed to have 1 or what criteria goes there?

Comment: @CeliusStingher when treatment is not X pass the whatever the doctor value is in that row. Please see the expected output!

Comment: Could you explain better? I dont't understand the criterion to pick the `nurse` values. Even looking at the expected output.

Comment: @Valentino Sure! when the treatment == X take the doctor value and pass it to the nurse and since there is a groupby('patient') that number should be the same until the next group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) + [Series.where](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html). Then stuffed with [ffill](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html):

```
df['nurse']=df.groupby('patient',sort=False).apply(lambda x: x['doctor'].where(x['treatment'].eq('X')).ffill()).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

---

```
     patient treatment doctor nurse
0       a         X      1     1
1       a         Y      2     1
2       a         Y      2     1
3       b         X      2     2
4       b         Z      3     2
5       b         Z      3     2
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. in R it is very simple 
`....
group_by(patient)%>%
mutate(nurse=ifelse(any(doctor=="X"),doctor,NA))`

Comment: I am glad to help!. Y update with sort=False. It is necessary for reset_index correctly